Can't remove file after Google Drive Synchronization
On Windows after Google Drive has synchronized my backup, I can't use the cli anymore to remove a directory with rmdir unless I use force, even when running as admin. The problem is that I use a 3rd party script (from Capacitor), which calls rmdir. I've already set the permissions to full control.
Now I can't keep my files synchronized, as I first need to manually remove all generated content before they can be overwritten each time a backup is made.
PowerShell: You do not have sufficient access rights to perform this operation.
Does anyone know how to solve this?
